# how to save the mode which is list as csv file

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to  save list as .csv file

I am using the "psych" to obtain cohen.kappa. I have the data(named as ic2) which have 1000 observations and 51 variables.

```
kappa <- function(ic2, colN) {
    tab <- vector("list", colN)
    for (i in seq_len(ncol(ic2))) {
    tab[[i]]=cohen.kappa(res[[i]])}
    tab}
a=kappa(ic2, ncol(ic2))
a
```

The output will be :

```
[[1]]
Call: cohen.kappa1(x = x, w = w, n.obs = n.obs, alpha = alpha)

Cohen Kappa and Weighted Kappa correlation coefficients and confidence boundaries 
                 lower estimate upper
unweighted kappa     1        1     1
weighted kappa       1        1     1

 Number of subjects = 1000 

[[2]]
Call: cohen.kappa1(x = x, w = w, n.obs = n.obs, alpha = alpha)

Cohen Kappa and Weighted Kappa correlation coefficients and confidence boundaries 
                 lower estimate upper
unweighted kappa  0.87      0.9  0.93
weighted kappa    0.87      0.9  0.93

 Number of subjects = 1000
```

so there are 51 outputs. And I want to save 51 output as one csv file. How could I save it?
I would like to save the output has 3 columns and two rows( row's names are unweighted kappa and weighted kappa; column's names are lower, estimate, and upper), because I will extract the estimate value from the output.

Comment: How exactly do you want to store this data in a csv file? What do you want that csv file to look like? It would be best if you updated your question to make that clear.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks! I update the more details in the question. I would like save the 51 outputs as csv which has 3 columns and two rows.

Comment: Figure out how to extract relevant data from your list element (try `str`), and it should be a simple lapply from there on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me what the other rating is that you are comparing to each of the 51 columns.  But here is an example that may help you do what you want.  I create a fake data frame like yours but smaller, only 10 rows and 5 columns.  I use the numbers from 1 to 10 as a reference rating for which Cohen's kappa is computed for each row.  The results are saved in a data frame with the same number of rows as the original data frame had columns, and 6 variables representing the lower, estimate, and upper of the unweighted and weighted kappa, respectively.

```
# fake data
ic2 <- data.frame(matrix(sample(1:5, size=10*5, replace=TRUE), nrow=10))

# reference rating ?
ref <- 1:nrow(ic2)

# Cohen's kappa
results <- data.frame(t(apply(ic2, 2, function(x) as.numeric(t(cohen.kappa(cbind(ref, x))$confid)))))
names(results) <- c("klo", "k", "kup", "kwlo", "kw", "kwup")
results
```

Comment: V.Adams  Thank you! That's what I want to do . It works for my data.